# Is it possible to specify check-out strategy?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-job-dsl

Is it possible in Jenkins-dsl to specify the SVN check-out strategy?

I would like to use "Use 'svn update' as much as possible", yet the only way I can see to configure this is manually

Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this

```
job {
  name 'svn2'
  description 'Build and test the app.'
  scm {
    svn('https://subversion.assembla.com/svn/chucknorrisaxis', localDir='.'){
      (it / 'workspaceUpdater').attributes().put 'class',
           'hudson.scm.subversion.UpdateWithCleanUpdater'
    }
  }
  steps {
    gradle 'test'
  }
  publishers {
    archiveJunit 'build/test-results/**/*.xml'
  }
}
```

I have a different update strategy here because I think the default strategy is 'use svn update as much as possible'

I asked the job dsl google group on your behalf (as my own solution failed) [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/job-dsl-plugin/1hV7YR_fF2w)

Incidentally, to try out job-dsl commands outside of Jenkins you can use the job-dsl [playground](http://job-dsl.herokuapp.com/)